# Transparent status bar in API 30

Tags: java, android, statusbar, transparent

Hello i have a transparent status bar in android and it's working in my old project and now i have new project and it is giving me warning for deprecated.

**code to transparent status bar**

```
activity.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
activity.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);                activity.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN );
activity.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
activity.getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(R.color.dark_background);
activity.getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

**New project Configuration**

```
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 30
```

**Old project Configuration**

```
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 29
```

**I know it's just because of API 30 any one know how to remove warning**

**Old Project SS**
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2G0A9.png

**New project SS**
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2uCA.png

Comment: You'd be better off posting code rather than images

Comment: Dear read my post i a have added both source code and image